# Python - Connect MySQL through localhost not working but 127.0.0.1 is working?

Tags: python, mysql

I just setup a VPS with a Mysql Database on it. I'm able to log into the database in the SSH terminal with `mysql -uroot -p` however, the python file shown below is unable to form a connection, and errors with `Access denied for root@localhost (using password: YES)`. I'm confused as to why this is happening. I'm 100% sure my password is correct. I'm using mysql.connector

Python file:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="pwd",
  database="db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO test (tests) VALUES (%s)"
val = ("testing")

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

I'm a bit new to this DB and VPS stuff, so please bear with me if I don't understand on the first go.

Thanks!

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and see if that works

Comment: Woah thats insane! It worked!! Can you explain why this works when localhost doesn't? I thought they were analogous. I've spent three days on this and it was that simple, wow.

Comment: i assume it has something to do with the dns not properly resolving localhost. I have experienced that before, but outside of just mapping localhost to 127.0.01 in the hosts file, i'm not sure of another way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @don's answer

> I assume it has something to do with the dns not properly resolving localhost. I have experienced that before, but outside of just mapping localhost to 127.0.01 in the host's file,

This can also be fixed by changing a value in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

It's likely your `bind-address` line is

```
bind-address = localhost
```

You can try changing it to

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

You can also set it to `0.0.0.0` but this will expose the connection to the outside world (inc. public IP), so this is highly not recommended but will solve the problem.